# MS SQL Server - How to define Table names from list in From clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how can I make below code work.  I got table names stored in temp table which I need to put in From clause

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
     TABLENAME NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #temp (TABLENAME)
VALUES            ('SALES'),
                  ('CUSTOMER'),
                  ('ORDERS')    

DECLARE @BranchID AS INT,
        @TABLENAME AS NVARCHAR(20),
        @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @BranchID = 8
SET @TABLENAME = (SELECT TABLENAME FROM #temp)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT [B@] AS BranchID , ' + @TABLENAME + ' AS TABLENAME
            FROM [DB001].[dbo].[' + @TABLENAME + ']
            WHERE [B@] = ' + @BranchID + '
            GROUP BY [B@]'
EXEC(@SQL)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
```

I want result to appear like below

```
BranchID | TABLENAME
--------------------
   8     | SALES
   8     | CUSTOMER
 NULL    | ORDERS
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the code. Also post the entire query

Comment: As a note:  `@BranchName` is not defined.  And, as constructed, your query cannot return `NULL` in the first column.  However, your question is about something else.

Comment: Think this part will also fail as it will return more than one value:    SET @TABLENAME = (SELECT TABLENAME FROM #temp)

Comment: Sorry it was typing mistake.

Comment: BranchName should be BranchID.  I  have corrected it in my question.

Comment: I want to know that how can I use multiple Table Names (which are listed in temp table) in FROM clause.  Basically I want to know that if BranchID 8 exists in any table of the Database. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes:

```
SELECT [B@] AS BranchID , ''' + @TABLENAME + ''' AS TABLENAME
```

You can also use parameters for this.  But since you have to munge the query string, that is less important.

Comment: Even `@BranchName` requires something like that. Either this  `''' + @BranchName + '''` or convertion to `varchar` if it is declared as `Int`

Comment: @Prdp . . . I don't see `@BranchName` defined in the question, so I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I doesn't understand very well what you are looking for, but I write you 2 examples I think that could help you.

```
`--Option 1 join tempname with branchid


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
     TABLENAME NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #temp (TABLENAME)
VALUES            ('SALES'),
                  ('CUSTOMER'),
                  ('ORDERS')    

DECLARE @BranchID AS INT,
        @TABLENAME AS NVARCHAR(20),
        @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @branchname as nvarchar(max)


set @branchname = 'asdf'
SET @BranchID = 8



select @BranchID as BranchId, tablename
from #temp

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp


--Option2 get data from table with name is in temptable for each table, but you must have to create that tables before


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
     TABLENAME NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #temp (TABLENAME)
VALUES            ('SALES'),
                  ('CUSTOMER'),
                  ('ORDERS')    

DECLARE @BranchID AS INT,
        @TABLENAME AS NVARCHAR(20),
        @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @branchname as nvarchar(max)


set @branchname = 'asdf'
SET @BranchID = 8


declare curhandler cursor for select tablename from #temp


open curhandler

fetch next from curhandler into @tablename

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @SQL = 'SELECT [B@] AS BranchID , ' + @TABLENAME + ' AS TABLENAME
            FROM [DB001].[dbo].[' + @TABLENAME + ']
            WHERE [B@] = ' + @BranchName + '
            GROUP BY [B@]'

    exec (@sql)
    fetch next from curhandler into @tablename
end

close curhandler
deallocate curhandler




IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp






SET @TABLENAME = (SELECT TABLENAME FROM #temp)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT [B@] AS BranchID , ' + @TABLENAME + ' AS TABLENAME
            FROM [DB001].[dbo].[' + @TABLENAME + ']
            WHERE [B@] = ' + @BranchName + '
            GROUP BY [B@]'
EXEC(@SQL)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp`
```

Comment: I want to know that how can I use multiple Table Names (which are listed in temp table) in FROM clause. Basically I want to know that if BranchID 8 exists in any table of the Database. So how can I do that?